# Images recover text using flex

Tags: react-native, layout, flexbox

I have problem to understand image management in react native.
I have followed tutorials, like Facebook's tutorial, but I still have problems:

I want to contain images and not them to spill and recover the text.
But Images are too big and recover the text.

```
<View style={styles.s2}>
  <View style ={flex:1}>
     <Text> text for test </Text>
  </View> 
  <View style ={styles.s1}>
     <Image style ={styles.s2}
            source={require("./images/im1.png")}/>
     <Image style ={styles.container}
            source={require("./images/im2.png")}/>
  </View>
  <View style ={flex:1}>
     <Text> text for test </Text>
  </View> 
</View>
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  s1: {
    flex: 0.3,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  s2: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    resizeMode: "contain",
  }
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong and how I could restrict images to the area defined by flex ratio ?

Answer (score 0):

resizeMode is a prop of the Image component. Use it like this

```
<Image 
    resizeMode='contain'
    style ={styles.s2}
    source={require("./images/im1.png")}
/>
```

For more info check the [docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode)

Comment: I have the same result if I integrate resizeMode='contain' inside image component